# Jquery add class to parent of an anchor tag not working

Tags: jquery

I want to give a class to the parent `li` tag after clicking on the `a` tag.
After clicking on the `a` tag it removes the class selected but I can not add it back.

```
<header class="main-header">
    <nav class="grid-container main-nav main-nav-big">
        <ul class="grid-12">
            <li class="liBig selected">
                <a href="#">Home</a>
            </li>
            <li class="liBig">        
                <a href="#">About</a>
            </li>
            <li class="liBig">
                <a href="#">Buy</a>
            </li>
            <li class="liBig">
                <a href="#">Contact</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </nav>      
</header>
```

```js
$("nav ul li a").click(function(){
    $("nav ul").children().removeClass("selected");
    $("this").parent().addClass("selected");
});
```

Comment: `$(this).parent().addClass("selected");` Use `this` without quotes

Comment: `$("this")` will match all the `<this>` elements in the page, which is not what you're looking for.

Comment: ahaha iam idiot , thank you guys for the fast answer !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to remove `" "` from `this`, it is not a string and use `e.preventDefault`.

```
$("nav ul li a").click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $("nav ul").children().removeClass("selected");
        $(this).parent().addClass("selected");
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your fast answer! Can you tell me please why should i use the preventDefault?

Comment: So when you click on this a, it will append an # in the url. Which you don't want. So preventdefault basically stops the propagation of default behavior.